# Whats the password?

Tags: permissions, ssh, password

Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntu@172.16.1.102's password:

ive been trying to log into Anbox Cloud for the first time, at the moment im trying to get into the website a it gives you a command to type in "ssh ubuntu@172.16.1.102" when i do that its asking me to imput a password to get into it, only issue is that it's not a password that i've set

I recently created this PC a week ago so its completely fresh with nothing installed on it along with no programs being installed i have been able to set up EVERY SINGLE PASSWORD ON THE MACHINE AS THE SAME WORD and when it asks for numbers its the SAME SET OF NUMBERS. Neither password works for this so im confused as its not like i've set a password to anything in the last week i would forget, i have also tried the password to the wifi network i am on to see if it worked and that also did not work so any help would be great as ive been stuck here trying to google this for about a day now.

so i have to ask Ubuntu whats the password?

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://anbox-cloud.io/docs/tut/installing-appliance), everything is done though the web interface using your Ubuntu One credentials. There is no need to SSH into the device 

Comment: Anbox Cloud Appliance

The Anbox Cloud Appliance lets you stream mobile apps securely, at any scale, to any device letting you focus on your apps. Learn more at anbox-cloud.io

You're almost there, to finish the installation log onto the machine via SSH and run the following command:
$ ssh ubuntu@172.16.1.102
$ sudo anbox-cloud-appliance init                                                      im a little new to linux how would i run this command line through a web interface like you said if this is the commands supposed to run do i just type them into the search bar or something?